# Firefox open URL only if not exist

Tags: firefox, vbscript

I have made this script so it check for new content, it works fine, my only problem is that I would like to only open the URL if its not being loaded. and my script is this one

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim WebPage(2)
WebPage(0) = "http://domain/page.aspx?page=1"
WebPage(1) = "http://domain/page.aspx?page=2"
waitTime= 60000 'wait period in milliseconds

Do
  Set o = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  o.Run "firefox.exe " & WebPage(i)
  WScript.Sleep waitTime
  Set o = Nothing 

  ' check our loop
  i = i + 1

  ' reset no
  If i = 2 Then
    i = 0
  End If
Loop
```

Comment: Open *which* URL if *what* doesn't exist?

Comment: Open only if URL is not in firefox tabs, sorry

Comment: That's not possible with VBScript, since Firefox doesn't expose a COM object VBScript could use.